# Error to make toast on asyntask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My problem is i'm traying to make toast if user fail to loged on database but the toast still came up  even the user succses loged in my database  `Login_layout`.

```
 class BuatLogin extends AsyncTask<String,  String , String> {

    /**
     * Sebelum memasuki menu buat progres dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_layout.this);
      pDialog.setMessage("Login_layout Progress...");
      pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
      pDialog.setCancelable(true);
      pDialog.show();
    }
    /**
     * Konkesi
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
      String usr = user.getText().toString();
      String pwd = pass.getText().toString();

      Log.d("1 "+usr, pwd);
      // Building Parameters
      List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usr", usr));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", pwd));
      Log.d("2 "+usr, pwd);
      Log.d(usr,url_create_login);

      // getting JSON Object
      // login url menerima POST method
      JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_login,
                                                   "POST", params);

      // cek log untuk response
      Log.d("Buat Respond", json.toString());

      // check untuk sukses tag
      try {
        int sukses = json.getInt(TAG_SUKSES);

        if (sukses == 1) {
          String nim=json.getString(TAG_NIM);
          Log.d(TAG_NIM,nim);

          // sukses login
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Mhs_main_layout.class);
          i.putExtra(TAG_NIM, nim);
          startActivity(i);

          // tutup layar
          finish();
        } else if(sukses == 2) {
          String nim=json.getString(TAG_NIM);
          Log.d(TAG_NIM,nim);
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Admin_main_layout.class);
          i.putExtra(TAG_NIM, nim);
          startActivity(i);

          // tutup layar ini
          finish();
        }else if(sukses == 3){

             setResult(100);


        }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return null;     
    }   

  }


  protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {       
  int resultCode = 100;
        if (resultCode == 100) {
    Toast.makeText(Login_layout.this, "Nip/Nim Atau Password TIdak Sesuai Silahkan Coba            Lagi ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
pDialog.dismiss();

  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `onProgressUpdate(Progress...values)` method, which is made for exactly what you want. In `doInBackground()`, call `publishProgress(Progress...values)` and make the `Toast` there.

And btw: please consider reading books about code quality, object-oriented programming, and while you're at it, read the Android API documentation.

**EDIT/ADDITION**

Basis AsyncTask overview (and remember, you are starting a new `Thread` with an `AsyncTask`)

```
public class Operation extends AsyncTask<ParamA, ParamB, ParamC> {
    @Override
    protected ParamC doInBackground(ParamA... params) {
        return new ParamC();
    }      

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ParamC result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(ParamB... values) {

    }
}
```

where `ParamA`, `ParamB` and `ParamC` are just classes to show what is used where:

```
private class ParamA { }
private class ParamB { }
private class ParamC { }
```

When you execute the operation by `new Operation().execute(new ParamA());`, first `onPreExcute` is called to instantiate some variables you might need (like setting up a connection). Then the given params in `execute` are put as params in `doInBackground`. When that's finished, the return from `doInBackground` is passed as param into `onPostExecute`, where you can show your result.

In `doInBackground`, you can publish results to the UI-thread. The shortcut is using `publishProgress` in `doInBackground`, as you cannot call the UI-thread directly from `doInBackground` (because the `AsyncTask` is another `Thread`, which does not run on the UI-thread).

**ACTUAL USEFUL EXAMPLE**

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AsyncTaskActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button button;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Click to start operation");
        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("NOT STARTED YET");
        linearLayout.addView(button);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        setContentView(linearLayout);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        if (view == button)
            new LongOperation().execute("Hello");
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {
        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            for(int i = 1; i < params[0].length(); i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    publishProgress(i, i*i); //proper way to publish results while task is running.
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return new Random().nextDouble();
        }      

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
            textView.setText("Done: random result is " + result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(AsyncTaskActivity.this, "onPreExcecute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            textView.setText("We just slept for a total of " + (values[0] * 2) + " seconds,  (and btw: " + values[0] + " to the power of 2 is " + values[1] + ").");
        }
    }   
}
```

You can also access the UI-thread in other `Threads` (or `doInBackground`) by this code (although you should try to avoid it):

```
AsyncTaskActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textView.setText("Called the UI from Thread");
    }
});
```

Comment: can you give a for example..?

Comment: I'd suggest accepting above answer, since it solved your initial problem, and creating another question with the newly arisen problem.

Comment: sory sir i'm dummy, i dont understand what do you mean??

Comment: Post your new problem on StackOverflow as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve, when, and how. Anyways, that `return null"` looks damnly bad there.

You should return some useful information to post execute. Maybe there you could check if the result is the one expected.

A function should never return a "random" result. 
You should try to relearn some OOP and/or java.
You're returning a "null" for sure, and you programmed that function to return a `String`.

**After saying that...**
You should write the code to generate the Toast message in `onPostExecute` as it have access to the view.

**Edit**
Is logcat saying error in this line `Toast.makeText(Login_layout.this...`?
I'm not sure if its well written. Some1 please comment it, but I think you should write `v.getContext()` instead of `Login_layout.this`